# fstring in JSON, ValueError: Invalid format specifier, Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following code:

```
import json

domain="abc.com"

rawlog = json.loads(
            f'{"domain": ${domain}}')
            
print(rawlog["domain"])
```

Which gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
>
```

The question is, what is the cause and if I can have fstring in Json? I'm using the newest Python: `python3 --version` shows `Python 3.10.4`.

I also tried:

```
import json

domain="abc.com"

rawlog = json.loads('{"domain": f'{domain}'}')
            
print(rawlog["domain"])
```

but it gives:

```
File "<string>", line 5
    rawlog = json.loads('{"domain": f'domain'}')
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `{` and `}` have special meaning they need to be escaped to mean literal `{` and literal `}`, consider following simple example

```
import json
domain="abc.com"
string=f'{{"domain": "{domain}"}}'
parsed=json.loads(string)
print(parsed)
```

gives output

```
{'domain': 'abc.com'}
```